# How do I loop through page number present in api using angular js

Tags: angularjs, api

I am accessing data from an api. I have set pageSize to be 100 in the request data, so there would be multiple pages in which data would be returned. Currently, I am getting only data present in last page. Is there a way that i can loop through the page numbers and store all the data together?

the result api looks like this:
[image]

So I want to loop through &page=1 until no next page exists.
The way I am doing $http.get is :

```
function userEventData (resp) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: resp.results["@href"]
            }).success(function (responseData) {
                logger.info("userEventData responseData", responseData);
                filterEventField(responseData);
                //return responseData;
            });
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So the problem is that you are only getting data from the last page? Why is that? Where is your loop and what are you doing with the data? Is it that the log only shows the last page data?

Comment: No the reason i am getting only last page data is because i am not accessing all pages. So its giving me the most recent one. If i loop through all pages and access data then i will have data from every page. I am not able to figure out how should i loop through a value thats inside the url.

Comment: Do you know how many pages there are ahead of time?  Is the API going to get mad if you make lots of simultaneous calls?

Comment: no i wouldn't know how many pages would be there ahead of time. i think we will have to make api call anyways.

Comment: You just need to build a new url each time and keep calling it until you no longer get any data back (assuming you don't have a way to get the page count).

Comment: can you please add some pseudo code?

Comment: Okay, you're going to need to something fairly complex with recursion and promises where you grab one page at a time until you have them all.

I was hoping to rough something out for you but it's turning out to be trickier than I thought

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling $http directly from your controller - you shouldn't do that in angular anyway, and you definitely shouldn't do it in a case like this.

Instead, you're going to want to call a service that gets all the data.  Your controller will do something like this.  This expects GetData() to return a promise.  When that promise is resolved, it does something with the data.

```
function userEventData (resp) {
    PagedDataService.GetData().then(function(data) {
        filterEventData(data)
    });
}
```

This version of the service should work, although you'll need to fill in the code for adding information to "data" and for determining if there's another page.

Note that the $http response object has several properties to let you determine what happened with the http request.  `r.data` will contain the actual response from the API, assuming the request was successful.

```
app.factory("PagedDataService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
   var data = [];
   var deferred;

   function GetPageRecursive(pageNumber) {
     var promise = $http.get('url', { page: pageNumber} ).then(function(r) {
        // add results to data here
        // also figure out if there's another page to get
        if(AnotherPage)
          GetPageRecursive(pageNumber ++)
        else
          deferred.resolve(data);
     })
     return promise;
   }

   return {
      GetData: function() {
        deferred = $q.defer();

        GetPageRecursive(1);

        return deferred.promise
      }

   }
}]);
```

Comment: @user2128, give this a shot.  It's still not perfect code but it should point you in the right direction.  $q and promises can be tricky but they're also some of the cooler things in angularjs.

Answer (score -1):

You can do actions in your success block. For instance you might add new data to an array. Or trigger another server call to get the next page of data. This would allow you to get the data in sequence.

Alternatively you could have a `for` loop to trigger 100 http calls. That might be slow though. Maybe you only want to fetch the data when you need it? Perhaps based on some user action like scrolling or pressing a button.